# How is possible to get 2d transformation css vertical way

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have this  with the following `CSS 2d Transforms` code that built a `h2` in horizontal way from the Left side of the Content to the Right. 
I'd need the same effect but in the "vertical way", from bottom to top.
Furthermore, I' like to have a gradient color effect from green to Red.

You can find the demo here [Link](https://miketricking.github.io/dist/) EFFECT 12

```css
.hovereffect {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
  background: #42b078;
}

.hovereffect .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 50px 20px;
}

.hovereffect img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  max-width: none;
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(-10px,0,0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.hovereffect:hover img {
  opacity: 0.4;
  filter: alpha(opacity=40);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.hovereffect h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 17px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.hovereffect h2:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
}

.hovereffect:hover h2:after {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.hovereffect a, .hovereffect p {
  color: #FFF;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
}

.hovereffect:hover a, .hovereffect:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <div class="hovereffect">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x250" alt="">
    <div class="overlay">
      <h2>Effect 12</h2>
      <p> 
        <a href="#">LINK HERE</a>
      </p> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to create a vertical variation of your design, please consider the below effect:

```css
.hovereffect,
.hovereffect img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.overlay {
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.overlay p {
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(-100vh);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
.hovereffect h2 {
  position: relative;
}
.hovereffect h2:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 5px;
  background: tomato;
  transform: translateY(100vh);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
.hovereffect:hover p,
.hovereffect:hover h2:after {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
}
.hovereffect:hover h2:after{left:0;width:100%;}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <div class="hovereffect">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x250" alt="">
    <div class="overlay">
      <h2>Effect 12</h2>
      <p>
        <a href="#">LINK HERE</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi thanks for your answer.  actually my intention  was to get the same effect of the original content(bar Chart effect).  But not from the left side of the Div but from the bottom(whti Bar Chat Effect)

Comment: bar chart effect? not entirely sure what you mean? Something like [this?](https://jsfiddle.net/069ue3nt/)

Comment: Yes like that!  Thanks a  lot! So now inverting the height and widht  I have a chart effect. Just one more question. Is possible to have more than one bar into the same div?  Could you give a little explanation about what you did?

Comment: So, I can have max 2 lines?. there's  no  way to have more lines? Something like this? http://elearningmojo.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Bar-Growth-Chart-Thumbnail.jpg

Comment: Thanks a lot. Save my day!